# Convert string to int after reading data from CSV file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read data from a csv file into a vector of structs each containing various values from a football game (offensive team, quarter, down, yards to go, play desc, etc). I'm trying to use stringstream to convert strings to ints but i'm returning junk data.

```
Data d;  //structs
vector<Data> TeamData;  //vector of structs
string s;
istringstream iss( s );

ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("CSV file here");  //open CSV file


while (  !myfile.eof()  )
{
getline (myfile, d.gameid, ',');  //read to comma, store in d.gameid

getline (myfile, s, ',');  //read to comma
iss >> d.qtr;             //use stringstream to store into d.qtr

repeat for remaining values . . .
```

The cvs file looks similar to this if you're wondering:

```
20070906_NO@IND,1,47,25,IND,NO,1,10,31,(2:25) J.Addai up the middle to NO 27 for 4 yards (S.Fujita).,0,0,2007
20070906_NO@IND,1,46,42,IND,NO,2,6,27,(1:42) P.Manning pass deep left to M.Harrison for 27 yards TOUCHDOWN.,0,0,2007
```

My program returns data like this when i try to output everything of relevance:

```
Game ID: 20070906_NO@IND
Offensive team: IND
Quarter: 7077994
Down: 4696320
To go: 4670480
Play: (2:25) J.Addai up the middle to NO 27 for 4 yards (S.Fujita).

Game ID: 20070906_NO@IND
Offensive team: IND
Quarter: 7077994
Down: 4696320
To go: 4670480
Play: (1:42) P.Manning pass deep left to M.Harrison for 27 yards TOUCHDOWN.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`istringstream` copies the string you pass it in the constructor, so changes you make to the string following that won't have any effect on the stream. You should construct a new stream, or call the `istringstream:str()` method to supply a new string, every time the string changes.

```
getline (myfile, s, ',');  //read to comma
iss.str(s);                // supply new string to stream
iss >> d.qtr;              //use stringstream to store into d.qtr
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at my answer for 'reading floats'
Instead of parsing on whitespace parse on commas.

[Using ifsstream to read floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100662/using-ifstream-to-read-floats/22103121#22103121)